# convert vertical sql result into horizontal output

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table, #t with 16 rows:
  id           int
  description  varchar(60)
  balance      decimal(6,2)

I need the description & balance data, and "select description, balance from #t order by id" will do the job. But ideally, I could do with showing the results horizontally rather than vertically.

Now I know I can build a new table with 16 columns and populate the balance for each such column using much dynamic sql, but, I'm also sure that this can be done a good deal more easily using pivot or something like that - though I dont really understand how.

Can someone please enlighted me?

Thanks
John

Comment: Dear John: Pray tell, which RDBMS are you using? Each vendor tends to have their our implementation that may apply to your scenario.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server you can implement the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to convert the rows of data into columns.  The basic syntax will be:

```
select *
from 
(
  select description, balance
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  sum(balance)
  for description in ([desc1], desc2])  -- replace this with the names of your descriptions
) piv;
```

Of course if you have an unknown number of description values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(description) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select description, balance
               from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(balance)
                for description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query
```